# Where should I save game object's attributes (hp, score) in Swift?

Tags: collision-detection, gameobject, spritekit, swift

**Scenario:** I have a game with several game objects on screen. Each can have different score and hitpoints. When I use collision detection for cannonball vs. ship (example) I need to know which ship is hit and how much hitpoints it has.

**Problem:** I had several approaches from extending [`SKSpriteNode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812108/how-to-know-which-skspritenode-is-affected-by-collision-detection-in-swift) or [`SKPhysicsBody`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842864/how-to-call-a-designated-initializer-of-the-superclass-skphysicsbody/31843541#31843541) but all failed. SKSpriteNode doesn't work, because Swifts collision detection only returns physicsBody and since you can't extend physicsBody, it didn't work to save there ships attributes as well.

**Question:** What would be a good approach to save such data to my game objects? I do not need code - because I think I can write it myself - but I would be happy to read a good suggestion. But if you have already some code written and a good solution for this problem, I would not be angry to read it ;)

Comment: Because I try to avoid change core classes. And I am not in a hurry - so I might find a better solution. Otherwise this would be a good way thought. But I have still hope that there is a more 'common' solution in Swift for my problem. How do all the other game developer it?

Comment: From [SKPhysicsBody.h](https://github.com/luisobo/Xcode-RuntimeHeaders/blob/master/SpriteKit/SKPhysicsBody.h) it seems that there is a reference to `SKNode`, how come that didn't work for you ? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772869/how-to-get-skspritenode-by-physicsbody) definitely seems correct. I suppose you have to cast the `physicsBody.node` instance to `Orange` (as long as `Orange` extends `SKNode`).

Comment: Hmm... physicsBody is attached to SKSpriteNode.physicsBody. But physicsBody returns just SKNode as parent tought.

Comment: You need to type cast it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SKPhysicsBody instances as keys to a dictionary of game objects.  When you want to process a collision, retrieve the game object associated with the physics body from the dictionary.  Not as efficient as the direct link you sought, but more than sufficient for most purposes.

Comment: I do it that way now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812108/how-to-know-which-skspritenode-is-affected-by-collision-detection-in-swift/31922288#31922288

Answer (score -1):

Try Using

**NSUserDefaults** it has the full CRUD functionality and you can save each ship type with their specific hit points and cannonball

More description about NSUserDefaults is **[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)**